# Vue: automatic rendering some components and make theirs methods accessible globally

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some components which must be globally reusable after single rendering.

They have some methods must be accessible from any template or other methods, e.g.

```html
<button @click="Confirm('Are you sure?')">REMOVE</button>
```

or

```js
//...
this.RaiseError("Something went wrong, sorry.");
//...
```

Now I try to register these components via plugin but have some issues with auto rendering.

```js
const Workbench = {
  install (Vue, options) {
    let ComponentClass = Vue.extend(Component)
    let instance = new ComponentClass(options)
    instance.$mount() //some components become visible but some others are not

    Vue.prototype.RaiseError = function (message) {
      instance.add(message, 'error')
    }
  }
}
export default Workbench
```

Is there a way to make it without `Vuex` and `refs`?

May be there's other patterns to make components globally accessible without littering?

Comment: what about vue observable https://vuedose.tips/tips/creating-a-store-without-vuex-in-vue-js-2-6/

Comment: I see just a "store" working from the box. Using `store` pattern in this case I just get tons of scattered code with awkward API. Or I just wrong understand your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution found:

```js
import MyComponent from '../components/MyComponent'

const MyPlugin = {
  mountComponent (Vue, Component, options) {
    let ComponentClass = Vue.extend(Component)
    let instance = new ComponentClass(options)

    //mounting the component to an independent DOM node
    instance.$mount(document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')))
    return instance
  },

  install (Vue, options) {
    //Vue creates and mounts the component when you call Vue.use(MyPlugin)
    let component = this.mountComponent(Vue, MyComponent, options)

    //now we can bind any component's methods to Vue instances
    Vue.prototype.Confirm = async function (title, text) {
      return await component.run(title, text)
    }
  }
}
export default MyPlugin
```

So we got automatically created component which state we can control wherever we need